# Angular quill: stop importing mention and emoji in each component

Tags: angular, typescript, quill

In order to use `<quill-editor>` in my components I always need to import 'quill-mention' and 'quill-emoji' in the TS file.

Where and how can I import those two dependencies in order not to have them in each component?

[image: the two mandatory imports]

Without those two imports I'd see many quill related errors in the console:

[image: errors generated by the lack of the two imports]